# Finding duplicate rows in MySQL, this query should fail but it returns something: what?

Tags: mysql

In Oracle it would fail, since hr_descr2 has one dozen of column the query is not ANSI valid, but on MySQL it returns a resultset, but not the one I was expecting. I thought it to be similar to the resultset returned by the second query, but it seems more like a select *

```
select *
from hr_descr2 ds2
group by ds2.titolo
having count(1) > 1
order by titolo;

select titolo, count(1)
from hr_descr2 ds2
group by ds2.titolo
having count(1) > 1
order by titolo;
```

I was expecting the query to do this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    hr_descr2
WHERE
    titolo IN (SELECT 
            titolo
        FROM
            hr_descr2 ds2
        GROUP BY ds2.titolo
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)
ORDER BY titolo;
```

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what you expect it to do?

Comment: To me: `select` from table `hr_descr2` with attribute (?) `ds2`, grouped by column `ds2.titolo` with more than `1`, ordered by `titolo`.

Comment: @Jonast92: added the expected behavior, but what I wonder is: what the creator of mysql expected to do... in oracle is not a valid query

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicate that the first query works, I will assume that the `hr_descr2` table only has a single column: `titolo`.  Otherwise, it should throw an error because of a non-aggregate value used with a `group by`.

Therefore, it returns a list of distinct `titolo` values which are duplicated and tells you how many times they occur.

Comment: No! that's the weird thing. This table has a dozen of column. The query should not work, but I've discovered that it's plotting every value from only one of each duplicated record.

Comment: Try not using `select *`.  Specify precisely what you want.